# CSS line-clamp issue with long words when line started with short one

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to add dots after 2 lines if text is too long so i decided to use `line-clamp`. But in case if my line starts with word and second word is too long to fit in line dots appear after short word without showing part of long word with dots. I dont want to use `word-break: break-all;` because it also break short words like "cat".

Do you have idea how to show part of this long word using only CSS, without any JS or `<wbr>` html tags?

```css
p {
   width: 300px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lalalal cat VeryLongLastWordThatShouldBePartVisibleButIsntBecauseCatBefore</p>
```